# WebRTC (for video chatting) Adobe AIR ANE for android and iOS

Tags: actionscript-3, air, webrtc, twilio, tokbox

Is there some ANE or possible other solution for using WebRTC (mainly for video chat) in Adobe AIR (AS3) for mobile ? There are some third party sdks like Twilio or TokBox but they only provide native solutions.

I really need a solution for having cross-platform (or any kind of) good quality video conferencing/chatting library for AIR (android and iOS both).

Thanks